# Suspicious vote patterns tool has broken formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools

In the last column of [the suspicious votes tool](https://stackoverflow.com/admin/show-suspicious-votes?filter=week&minVotesCast=20), the last two links are mashed together and hard to read/click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've converted the nested table to our grid layout, which solves the spacing issue.

With you in the next build.