# Paginating on Suspicious Voting Patterns Moderator Tools page drops percentVotes Query Parameter?

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, pagination

When looking at the suspicious voting patterns moderator tool, when I try to navigate to page two for my query (the first page query being `https://gaming.stackexchange.com/admin/show-suspicious-votes?minVotesCast=5&percentVotes=20&upvotes=true&filter=Year`), it seems the `percentVotes` query parameter is dropped.  When I hover over the page 2 button, the URL displayed is `https://gaming.stackexchange.com/admin/show-suspicious-votes?page=2&filter=year&minvotescast=5`:

[image: page two button showing the URL https://gaming.stackexchange.com/admin/show-suspicious-votes?page=2&filter=year&minvotescast=5]

When I click this button, it navigates me to the link displayed, but the page returns no results.  This leads me to believe that the `percentVotes` parameter is being defaulted back to 50% (I assume that is the default), and that causes the request to return nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted on the mod team?

Comment: @Laurel I guess it could be, but I saw some other questions about this tool such as this one on Meta: [Suspicious vote patterns tool has broken formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285419/suspicious-vote-patterns-tool-has-broken-formatting)

Comment: @TimothyG. that was before there was a private Team for moderators so not relevant. I don't know what's the policy, but I assume if there is now a dedicated and private Team only for mods, anything related to mod tools should go there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We've recently done a complete overhaul on this page which nullifies this request as these filter options are no longer available. While we're currently testing the page out with the mods (as of July 20, 2023), the response to the improvements has been really positive and I'm excited that it's seen as a really useful change.

Apologies that it was broken for so long!

Comment: I did look at the new page. It definitely looks cleaner in my opinion.